# Passing PHP through JQuery.Ajax Post & Changing html

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, facebook-like

I'm trying to create a facebook style like/unlike link and I need to pass some php variables through the JQuery.  At the moment I'm passing:

```
<a class="likelink" href="like.php?id=****&username=****&type=****">Like</a>
```

But although this works it is refreshing the page and I want it to do it fluently like twitter or facebook, so I need to pass the id, username, etc through JQuery.Ajax post.  Can anyone tell me how this would be possible? Also then I want the .likelink to change to Unlike.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use an ajax request for the 'like' action and then change the class in the success callback function:

```
$('.likelink').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    url: 'like.php',
    data: {
      id: ***,
      username: ****,
      type: ****
    },
    success: function() {
      $('.likelink').removeClass('likelink').addClass('unlikelink');
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something along the lines of:

```
$('.likelink').on('click', function(e){
  var $this = $(this);
  $.get($this.attr('href'), function(){
    $this.addClass('liked').attr('href', unlikeLink).text('Unlike');
  });
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Thanks Bill but at this point I'm more interested in passing the actual variables through JQuery post

Comment: If it's already in the URL you don't need to. However, you can do $.get( url, { id: '123', username: 'Bill', type: 'answer' }, successCallback );

Comment: Oh right, I'm quite new to JQuery post but I used it for the registration forms so wanted to use it here too. I didn't know you could pass the <a> link through JQuery post. Are there any tuts on how to do it properly with a full example code that you know of?

Comment: I'm doing that in the code. You're not passing the whole link to post, just the href attribute.